# ReleaseComObject does not work in static method

Tags: c#, memory-management, com, interface, directshow

While testing my code, I came across a behavior that I find strange.

This:

```
if (_sampGrabber != null)
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_sampGrabber);
    _sampGrabber = null;
}
```

yields _sampGrabber==null, whereas after

```
ReleaseIfNotNull(_sampGrabber);
```

_sampGrabber still has its orignal value when using

```
public static int ReleaseIfNotNull(object comObject)
{
    int hr = 0;

    if (comObject != null)
    {
        hr = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObject);                
        comObject = null;
    }
    return hr;
}
```

_sampGrabber is a DirectShow SampleGrabber filter interface.

I am interested in an explanation for this behaviour. I came across it when writing tests using the Visual Studio Test Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to change the reference, you will need to change the signature like so:

```
public static int ReleaseIfNotNull(ref object comObject)
```

Changing the local reference to `comObject` inside `ReleaseIfNotNull` affects only its own (stack) copy, and won't affect any other references to it. MSDN on [`ref` and `out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)